# Multiple authentication providers (Database and Webservice) for Symfony 2

Tags: web-services, symfony, authentication

I need to implement an authentication for a Symfony 2 project with 2 user providers :

- my project database ;
- a third party webservice.

The process is quite simple : the user fills the authentication form with his username and password. Those info are first check against the user database and, if not found, the username and password are sent to a webservice that returns a 200 status code and a token if the user exists (another webservice will give me the user's role later).

Problem is, I should not add the users provided by the webservice to the database.

I first thought about using a custom UserProvider (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) but the method `loadUserByUsername` does not allow me to identify the user with it's password.

The solution I have in mind would be to create a user from the webservice to a temporary table, in order to identify the user from the database, but I'd rather implement a more elegant solution.

Any idea on how to do this the right way ?

Answer (score 3):

The UserProvider let's you fetch a User object after the user is authenticated, the UserProvider won't authenticate the user itself. I think what you will need is a custom Authenticator using the SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface.

Here is a good explanation of how to do this: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

Essentially the Authenticator will be called by symfony and authenticates the user credentials against your webservice. On success the user object will be fetched and returned (finally using the custom UserProvider).

Comment: Not to nitpick but the user is retrieved then they are authenticated.  An important distinction.  Symfony 2.4+ also has a new custom password authenticator.  I think it might work better than the api key.  Have not tried it but it seems to give you access to both username and password.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html